# Virtual function efficiency and the 'final' keyword

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vtable

Consider a program that has a class `Foo` containing a function `Foo::fn` declared like this:

```
virtual void fn();
```

and a subclass of `Foo` called `Bar`. Will declaring `Bar::fn` like this:

```
virtual void fn() override final;
```

cause calls to `fn` in `Bar` or subclasses of `Bar` to be any more efficient, or will it just keep subclasses of `Bar` from overriding `fn`? If calls are made more efficient using `final`, what is the simplest, most efficient method to define `Bar::fn` such that its functionality is exactly that of `Foo::fn`?

Comment: No. The compiler doesn't even know that `Bar` exists (assuming the most common case of it being in another translation unit with whole-program optimization disabled) when it's determining how to compile code that calls `Foo::fn`. Why are you worried about vtable size?

Comment: I suspect the vtable stays the same size but the final marks it so the compiler will not allow overrides in derived classes

Comment: There are typically no vtables in instances of classes. Instances contain vptrs.

Comment: A better question might be to ask when the vtable can be ignored. E.g. `void (Bar &b) { b.fn(); }`. This can ignore the vtable as it knows that `b.fn()` must call `B::fn`.

Comment: No it won't make the vtable smaller. Even if you've declared it final, it still needs to be in the vtable since you may invoke it through a base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `fn` is defined as `final` in `Bar`, the compiler can dispatch calls to `fn` through a pointer or reference to `Bar` statically since it knows that `Bar::fn` is the final overrider. For example, this program fragment:

```
struct Foo {
  virtual void fn();
};

struct Bar : Foo {
  void fn() final override;
};

void with_foo(Foo& o) { o.fn(); }
void with_bar(Bar& o) { o.fn(); }
```

compiles to ([See gcc.godbolt.org for details](http://goo.gl/Cxb1XO)):

```
with_foo(Foo&):
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    call    *(%rax)
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret

with_bar(Bar&):
    subq    $8, %rsp
    call    Bar::fn()
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

the call in `with_foo` is dynamically dispatched (`call *(%rax)` is an indirect call) through the vtable, but the call in `with_bar` statically dispatches to `Bar::fn()`.

The simplest method to make `Bar::fn` be the final overrider of `Foo::fn` without changing behavior is to define it to statically call `Foo::fn`:

```
struct Bar : Foo {
  void fn() final override { Foo::fn(); }
};
```

Comment: My knowledge of assembly is somewhat minimal, but this seems to be what I was looking for... In essence, this shows that the call to `Bar::fn` is more efficient when the instance of `Bar` is stored as a `Bar`, but there is no gain when it is stored as a `Foo`, correct?

Comment: @Conduit Correct. In general, there is no way for a compiler to statically determine that a `Foo*` or `Foo&` actually refers to a `Bar` instance.

Comment: Makes sense given a little thought. Exactly what I was looking for then - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've not EVER cared about the size of the vtable. It is typically relatively small, and there is only one per class declaration. What is much more bothersome is extra space taken up in the class instances, since, except for singleons, class instances are often many of. So adding extra elements into a class, in some way or another, will definitely affect the amount of memory. If it's REALLY bothering you that the vtable is too large, then doing some redesign so that there aren't so many different virtual member functions (perhaps splitting the class hierarchy into several classes) or fewer derived classes. But really, even if you have hundreds of classes, each with a hundred virtual member functions, it's still relatively small - 200 classes with 100 members would take up 20000 * 8 bytes per entry [64-bit architecture] -> 160KB. Surely the 20000 functions [yes, in theory, you only need ONE new function per derived class to need a new vtable, but that is rather a silly design, so unlikely in reality]

The purpose of the `final` keyword is to ensure that you don't derive from it further - this is useful for example if you have a basic class hierarchy where some particular function should not be "changed". Say for example you have:

```
class user_base
{
    public:
      virtual bool check_password(); {... magical code .. };
      virtual bool is_super_user() = 0;
};

class superuser : public user_base
{
    public:
      virtual bool check_password() final  
        { .... magical code ...
          ... extra checks to ensure no remote login... 
        }
      virtual bool is_super_user() final { return true; }

 };

 class user : public user_base
 {
  public:
      virtual bool is_super_user() final { return false; }
 };
```

You have to trick around a bit to ensure that `user_base` isn't used as a base-class for a `fake_super_user`, and of course, there are other BIG security issues with such a design, but it gives you some idea.

Comment: I think this pretty much covers what I was looking for, assuming that I'm correct about you stating that `final` is only used to ensure subclasses can't override the function, but doesn't affect the outcome post-compilation. It sounds like I may be misusing my terminology... I'm inferring from your answer that vtables are kept with the class. What is stored with the actual instances?

Comment: Never mind - found what I was looking for. Edited question to follow.

Comment: The class contains a pointer to the vtable(s) for the instance. [You can have multiple vtables in cases where there is multiple inheritance]